# Squaring a cross one more time

Tags: geometry, lateral-thinking, dissection

*This is the lateral-thinking fifth part to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/squaring-a-cross).*

[image: 1]]

In this cross shape, all twelve sides are the same length and all angles are right angles. What is the smallest number of cuts that can divide the cross into pieces that can be rearranged to form two squares such that the side length of the larger square is one-and-a-half times the side length of the other?

Rules:

- Each cut is a straight line, which can (but isn't required to) go across multiple pieces.
- Pieces cannot be altered except by cutting, until all cutting is done.
- After all cuts are made, pieces may be reflected, rotated, or moved, but cannot be resized, folded, removed, added, or altered in any other way.
- Pieces cannot overlap or cover themselves or each other.
- After the pieces are moved, edges that join two pieces are ignored, as if the pieces fused together. The rest of the edges must form the set of squares exactly; squares must be formed entirely of piece edges, and extra edges or pieces are not allowed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can do it in two cuts:

> [image] 
>  The outer boundary is 1.5 times the size of the inner.